# development環境のみにgemをインストールしたい。しかしうまくいかない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Rails内のファイルの何行目でSQLが発行されているかわかるgemを入れました。
https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace

```
group :development do
  gem 'active_record_query_trace'
end
```

RSpecなどのテストをするときはこのgemは動かないほうがテスト速度が早くなるかと推測し、上記のようにGemfileを記載しました。

さらに `config/initializers/active_record_query_trace.rbファイル` を作り

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

ActiveRecordQueryTrace.enabled = true
```

と記載しました。

RSpecを動かすと

```
% bundle exec rspec
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::Base.raise_in_transactional_callbacks= is deprecated, has no effect and will be removed without replacement. (called from <top (required)> at プロジェクト名/config/environment.rb:7)
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rspec)
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecordQueryTrace
  プロジェクト名/config/initializers/active_record_query_trace.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
  /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  プロジェクト名/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  プロジェクト名/spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `require'
  プロジェクト名/spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  プロジェクト名/spec/controllers/advertisements_controller_spec.rb:3:in `require'
  プロジェクト名/spec/controllers/advertisements_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `load'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `block in load_spec_files'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `each'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `load_spec_files'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `setup'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
  プロジェクト名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rspec:22:in `<top (required)>'
Coverage report generated for RSpec to プロジェクト名/coverage. 19 / 45 LOC (42.22%) covered.
```

というエラーがでました。
注：エラーメッセージ中の該当ディレクトリ名は「プロジェクト名」と置換しています。
（念のため記載しますが、development環境のRailsは問題なく動いています）

`group :development` と書いた以上は、テスト環境は `ActiveRecordQueryTrace` に関することは知るすべもないはずで（だって何もインストールされていないのだから）、このようなエラーが出ることが不思議です。

Comment: エラーメッセージは省略せずに記載してください。エラーが出ているソースの位置やスタックトレースなど重要な情報が記載されています。省略してもよいところいけないところの区別がつかないのであれば、コマンドを実行した結果をすべて記載してください。

Comment: たしかにスタックトレースもあったほうがよいですね。足しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すみません。自己解決しました。

`ActiveRecordQueryTrace.enabled = true`
を書くファイルを間違ってました。

development環境のみで使用するので、下記ファイル内に記載するのが正解です。
`config/environments/development.rb`